# Line Breaks Not Recognized in Google Script

Tags: google-sheets, line-breaks, google-forms

I am making a form and the line breaks are not working, which makes the returned information much more difficult to read.

I realized this is started happening after I added a replyTo to the Mailapp, but cannot find a way to fix the problem. I also tried \n and \r.

Any suggestions?

```
    function Initialize() {

  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();

  for(var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("SendGoogleForm")
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();

}

function SendGoogleForm(e) 
{  
  try 
  {      
    // Personal Info
    var timeStamp = e.values[0];
    var userName = e.values[1];
    var phone = e.values[3];
    var preferredContact = e.values[5];
    var affliation = e.values[6];
    var articleOrBook =e.values[7];
    var itemFrom = e.values[8];
    var deliverTo = e.values[9];

    // Emails
    var email = "interlibraryloan@holyfamily.edu";
    var userEmail = e.values[4];

    //Book Values
    var book = e.values[18];
    var bookauthor = e.values[19];
    var publisher = e.values[20];
    var year = e.values[21];
    var isbn = e.values[22];
    var edition = e.values[23];

    //Article Values
    var article = e.values[10];
    var articleauthor = e.values[11];
    var journal = e.values[12];
    var volume = e.values[13];
    var issue = e.values[14];
    var date = e.values[15];
    var pages = e.values[16];

    // Optional but change the following variable
    // to have a custom subject for Google Form email notifications
    var subject = "Interlibrary Loan Request Submitted";

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var columns = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
    var message = "";

    var userMessage = "Dear " + userName + ", \n\nThank you for submitting an Intercampus/Interlibrary Loan Request. We will notify you when \n\n" + book + article + " by " + bookauthor + articleauthor + "\n\n is available. \n\nIntercampus or Interlibrary Loan Service \ninterlibraryloan@holyfamily.edu \nHoly Family University \n267-341-3584";    

    // Only include form fields that are not blank
    for ( var keys in columns ) {
      var key = columns[keys];
      if ( e.namedValues[key] && (e.namedValues[key] != "") ) {
        message += key + ' :: '+ e.namedValues[key] + "\n\n"; 
      }
    }

    // This is the MailApp service of Google Apps Script
    // that sends the email. You can also use GmailApp for HTML Mail.

    MailApp.sendEmail(email, userEmail, subject, message);
    MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, email, subject, userMessage);

  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }

}
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be some issues with this [character not being preserved](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2945), though the escaping seems to have been at least partway [fixed](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=13).

If this is going into a formula bar, you want to use `"Hello"&CHAR(10)&"world!"` for the newline.

Otherwise you can [use paragraphs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph) instead:

```
 var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

 // Append a document header paragraph.
 var header = body.appendParagraph("A Document");
 header.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);

 // Append a section header paragraph.
 var section = body.appendParagraph("Section 1");
 section.setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);

 // Append a regular paragraph.
 body.appendParagraph("This is a typical paragraph.");
```

This is especially useful when viewing the output in HTML since a browser will tend to eliminate extra white-space, but a paragraph is well understood for the functionality you want.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Use template literal (i.e) between two backticks type your actual contents and variable names inside two curly braces.

```
`var userMessage = `Dear {userName},

Thank you for submitting an Intercampus/Interlibrary Loan Request. We will notify you when

book  article   by   bookauthor  articleauthor

is available.

Intercampus or Interlibrary Loan Service
interlibraryloan@holyfamily.edu
Holy Family University
267-341-3584;

MailApp.sendEmail(email, userEmail, subject, message);
MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, email, subject, userMessage);`
```